# NextJS: Send a JSON object to another page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm starting with NextJS and React. I've developed a page A where I retrieve data (a JSON object) from an API (using getServerSideProps() to do it in each request time) and then I show it. Then, I've some IconButtons to push and go to another page B. That's working ok. Then, which is the right way to send that JSON object to the page B to show some elements?

The code I've done is something like this:

Page A:

```
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import { params } from "../components/ApiParams";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const Chapter = ({ response }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Chapter</title>
      </Head>

      <div>
      {response.data.mainValue}
      <IconButton href="/chapters/secondPage">
                <ChevronRightIcon />
      </IconButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const getFetch = async (params) => {
  const chapterUrl = `https://localhost/chapter/data-provider`;
  const response = fetch(chapterUrl, params);
  return response;
};

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  try {
    const res = await getFetch(params);
    const response = await res.json();
    return { props: { response } };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in getServerSideProps function: ", error);
  }
};

export default Chapter;
```

Page B:

```
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";

export default function secondPage(){
   return(
          //Here I want use the response object I've got from API in Page A.
);
}
```

So, how is the right way to send that response object to Page B? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well based on the code you provided I can't see how you are getting to the 'secondPage' component but...

The options that come to mind are

- Pass this data as prop(s) *if you can*
- get this data from the secondPage `getServerSideProps`
- save this data to localStorage and retrieve it on secondPage...

```
const PageOne = () => {

  const saveDataToLocalStorage = (key, someData) => {
    localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(someData)
  }
  /* this function will save data to localStorage at the key you provide. Data 

in localStorage is a string, that is why the data must be converted to 

JSON string via 'JSON.stringify(...)'. */

  return (
  .....more code
}

---------------------------

const PageTwo = () => {

  const readDataFromLocalStorage = (key) => {
    if(localStorage[key]) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage[key])
      // do something with data
    }
    console.error('no data with that key')
  }
  /* this function will read data from localStorage at whatever key you 

provide as an argument. 'JSON.parse' to convert 

string to object. To clear localStorage data at a specific key use 

localStorage.removeItem('key goes here')*/

  return (
  .....more code
}
```

Comment: This line is who take me to secondPage after push over: `<IconButton href="/chapters/secondPage">`. About your answers, I didn't find how to pass the object as a prop. I don't want get the data again from API in secondPage because it is a big JSON object and it won't be the appropriate to get the minimal API consume. About save the data to a session storage, it would be good. How can I do it? Would you share a link or an example? Thanks.

Comment: @SebastianDiaz Not sure if you figured out a solution, but I added an example of localStorage to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I didn't finish to solve yet because currently I'm with another part of the project. That you mentioned would work but regarding I know the localStorage is part of the browser we use to access the webapp and I prefer manage this data directly into de webapp code without external dependences as the browser storage. Certainly this is a possible solution in general aspects to do it but it isn't the kind of solution I'm looking for my specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `useContext` hook. By using it you can give many parameters in a component and use them in subcomponents of it

**Context.js**

```
import React from "react";

export const Context = React.createContext();
```

We can just create a state, which will take **B** page with help of `Context.Provider`

**PageA.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {Context} from "./Context";
import B from "./PageB";

function A() {
    const {count, setCount} = React.useState(0);
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{count, setCount}}>
            <B />
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}

export default A;
```

Here we have to use the same context to access provided states
**PageB.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {Context} from "./Context";

function B() {
    {count, useCount} = React.useContext();
    return (
        <>
            <h3>{ count }</h3>
            <button onClick={() => {setCount(count+1)}} >+</button>
             <button onClick={() => {setCount(count-1)}} >-</button>
        </>
    )
}

export default B;
```

Finally, I would like to add that using context you can provide not only states but functions too.

Comment: Thanks. It would be a solution, I'll try with this in some hours and then I'll confirm how does it was. Where you wrote `{count, useCount}` I think you wanted to put `{count, setCount}`, right? Anyway I will try it.

Comment: Oh! Yes I meant `{count, setCount}`

Comment: I've to try it first :), I didn't yet but I'll.